# invalid_filename error when syncing upload directory

Tags: file-uploads, sync

When I tried to synchronize my upload directories I kept getting the "invalid_filename" error for all the files. What is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Focus Lab's EE master config so I had to add a trailing slash on my directory paths in the config file.

This is what I had:

```
 1 => array(
      'name'        => 'Images',
      'server_path' => $base_path . '/uploads/images',
      'url'         => $base_url  . '/uploads/images/'
 )
```

This is what fixed it:

```
 1 => array(
      'name'        => 'Images',
      'server_path' => $base_path . '/uploads/images/',
      'url'         => $base_url  . '/uploads/images/'
  )
```